# Getting error library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket XCode 7.3 after Git push and clone

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, cocoaasyncsocket

We have used pod to install Library. In one computer it is running fine. But when we pushed it into Git and cloned it, it's giving me this error :

> ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

We even copied the project using USB. We tried "pod install". But that doesn't work too. We both are using XCode 7.3

Comment: Go to `Build Settings` -> `Linking` -> `OTHER_LDFLAGS` and see if your library is there. Also check the paths in `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, the best way to clean up certain pods related issues is to clean up everything and run again.

I have this standard procedure that works whenever there is a linking error with cocoaPods.

1.Keep a backup! (This may completely break!)

2.Do a pod deintegrate Use this library --> https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate to call the pod deintegrate command to clean up everything with cocoa pods.

3.Clean up the project settings, by removing everything that was edited. (If you did it for some framework to work, then keep it) Remove search paths, framework header paths, other linker flags Remove configs, Remove Flags, Remove PCH if any Anything that is bold in build settings is edited, whatever is not done explicitly by you for some purpose, delete it to restore back to default value.

4.Delete the workspace, and any pod file from the directory.

4.Paste Back your main pod file from the backup.

5.Delete data from derivedFolder, window-->projects-->delete derived data

6.Do a clean (product --> clean), and even clean build folder (holding option, do product --> clean build folder)

7.Do a pod install

8.Build and run.

Everything should be restored back to happy states!

Comment: I'm using Xcode 10.1, and still having the same problem after trying this. Any more tips?

Comment: go to build setting -> library search path -> double click on it and add this 3 command: 
$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME) $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME) 
$(inherited)
clean and rebuild